# How to create an SQL Persisted Computed Column which values are derived from spatial column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, spatial-database

Our GDB is using the SQL native GEOMETRY data storage type (SQL 2012 Standard) and the spatial reference for this uses a unit of square feet. I want to create a (persisted) computed column which will populate another column as acres.

Using the following query I'm able to produce the results I want:

```
Select shape.STArea()/43560 as Area from DATAOWNER.CTF_STANDS
```

In setting up the computed column I used the following:
[image: Computed Text]

Editing on the front end GIS application (ArcGIS), the Shape.STArea() field updates during edits, but updates to my computed column fail to happen.

I think that Shape.STArea is actually a function and appears to be enforced/maintained by the SDE/GDB Schema itself, so working with spatial column appears to be the best way forward.

I don't want to convert the Geometry column itself to another unit, but rather use it to populate another column via a formula which converts square feet to acres.

How do I create a computed column which will derive acres from the geometry column who's current values are in square feet?

[This other SE post's answer is very similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572806/trigger-for-insert-and-update-on-same-table)

Comment: Maybe it's just the end of a long day, but I don't see a question here.  Could you edit this to include a question mark not in parenthesis?  As it stands, I can't tell if you want help creating a query, or a view, or a new column.

Comment: I want to create a computed column (the MSSQL term) using either the geometry column or the existing values from shape.starea() which calculates acres from the existing square feet units.

Comment: Please edit your question to revise it with the requested clarification and be sure to include a single question mark somewhere so that what you are asking is clear.

Comment: So you are saying that the value is shown in your GIS application, but when you edit your spatial data or add a new record, this column is not updated?

Comment: I will edit question tomorrow for format and clarity. Thanks for keeping this in line.

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller yes that's exactly right.

Comment: @Vince I updated the question per your request. I've been out of the office/state for over a week, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Why use a computed column at all if it doesn't recompute? A view would be used in any other database.

Comment: @Vince I'm hoping that i'm just doing something wrong, otherwise, a computed column that recomputes is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @PolyGeo Would I be better off taking this to StackOverflow or would I be violating a cross-post policy?

Comment: You can always flag your own question to request its migration to Stack Overflow or DBA SE but in this case I suspect your best answers are likely to come from here so I would recommend working on frequent revisions to address any requested clarifications.

Comment: W.r.t. cross-posting http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234495/how-to-ask-the-same-question-on-different-sites/234497#234497

Comment: I would say that your question now only related to how to created a computed column in ArcGIS

Comment: only on the RDBMS backend; this shouldn't have anything to do with the front end application unless i'm missing something. Computed columns are different than field calculations (even if scripted) in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You have create a computed column in your database. This also means that it's up to the database to actually calculate the value in this column.

As a result, you'll only see an updated value when the record has been recalculated by the database. Changing part of the record within your GIS might not tricker the database to recalculate the value.

If you were working with MapInfo Professional the recalculation wouldn't happen until you saved your change to the database and potentially refreshed the current view of the data in MapInfo Professional. The last part does depend on whether you are using a live or a linked table connecting to the database.

I know you probably aren't using MapInfo Professional, but I'm guessing any application might work in a (more or less) similar way.

A solution to this would be to have your GIS application add and calculate this value to the table.

Comment: I would have thought that if the computed column was 'persisted', the value would be updated 'automatically'. After all, shape.STArea() is updated even before committing your edits in the GIS application. I'm aware of the option to script this in the GIS front-end, but that would still need to be executed by the end-user so I don't see that as a viable option for the workflow I'm trying to achieve here. Certainly, there must be a way to handle this on the RDBMS back-end.

Comment: Where can you see that Shape.STArea() is updated before committing your edits? Do you have that as a column as well?

Comment: While performing spatial edits in ArcMap, the Shape.STArea() & Shape.STLength() dynamically update upon completing an edit. You can see these fields in the attribute table in ArcMap. Creating a persisted spatial column with some kind of conversion seems to be the right path which is why I think I should maybe take this to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the ESRI products, but I think the two columns you are talking about are dynamic column updated by the Arc product itself and not by the database

Comment: I have removed the possibility of working with Shape.STArea() as a viable option in this question. I think the answer lies in working directly with the spatial/GEOMETRY column itself.